# Trying to build a scale using For, If and Offest loops

Tags: vba

I compose a code ,which take "Samples" spreadsheeet with a depth database and displays the numbers in "Log"

```css
Sub Log()


 
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 4


   Sheets("Samples").Select
   
   Sheets("Log").Select
   If Value <= 0.2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C9").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value < 0.4 And Value > 0.2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C10").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value <= 0.5 And Value >= 0.4 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C11").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 0.5 And Value < 0.9 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C12").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value < 1 And Value >= 0.9 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C13").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 1 And Value < 1.2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C14").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 1.2 And Value <= 1.5 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 1.5 And Value < 1.8 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C16").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 1.7 And Value < 1.9 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C17").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value >= 1.9 And Value < 2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C18").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 2 And Value < 2.2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C19").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value >= 2.2 And Value < 2.4 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C20").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value >= 2.4 And Value <= 2.5 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C21").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 2.5 And Value < 2.8 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C22").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value >= 2.8 And Value < 3 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C23").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 3 And Value < 3.2 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C24").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value >= 3.2 And Value <= 3.5 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C25").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 3.5 And Value < 3.7 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C26").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value >= 3.7 And Value <= 3.9 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C27").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 3.9 And Value < 4 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C28").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   End If
   
Next i
  
   

End Sub
```

spreadsheet, a depth scale.

The problem is that i use Offset and the loop does not work on the whole database. The loop stars on B6 until B13 on "Samples" spreadsheet.
Here is what I have done already

Comment: With the loop going from 1 to 4, it only covers B6 to B9 I guess. Is that what you mean that it doesn't go on until it reaches B13?

Comment: not maily, it just print B9 on the wrong place on the scale. If I run it without a loop ( just B6) it works perfect.

Comment: It seems that the loop reduce (-1) each period. Should i set  Range("B6") as String/Object?

Comment: In your case, you are correct to use -1, because the offset means that it will move a certain amount of rows from the given range. Because you want to start at B6 and you start with i =1, the first offset should be zero rows and 1 -1 = 0. But what happens when you reach B9? Where does it place a value and where should it place a value?

Comment: I think the problem lies in your if-statements, because they are not exclusive. Here for instance: ElseIf Value > 1.5 And Value < 1.8 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C16").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1)
   ElseIf Value > 1.7 And Value < 1.9 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("C17").Value = Sheets("Samples").Range("B6").Offset(i - 1).

Comment: Alex, it should not be exlusive since there scale marks 1,2,3 and 4.

Comment: I set B9 as 2.1 and it places it at the begining of the scale at C9. futhermore any number i would set, the output be in C9( as 0 on the sacle)

Comment: And Value in this case should be the value of B9? In that case you should use Sheets("Sample").Range("B6").offset(i-1).Value there. To make it easier, I would suggest you first make a variable: celvalue = Sheets("Sample").Range("B6").offset(i-1).Value and use the variable celvalue in all your if-statements instead of Value

Comment: it's not working.... the scale it is in the "Log" spreadsheet so that C9=0 C13=1 C18=2 C23=3 C28=4. I want to put the numbers betwean the scale marks.